# Spring Cloud Contract - Node.js as producer

Tags: javascript, node.js, spring, spring-cloud-contract, contract

My team is creating 2 microservices. One in Spring - consumer and another in Node.js - producer.
They will communicate through http rest api.

We would like to test them using contract.
I've seen https://spring.io/blog/2018/02/13/spring-cloud-contract-in-a-polyglot-world
but it's a different case (producer is on Java side and consumer is on Js).

Is there a way to define contract and generate tests for both microservices in such case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a standard contract test with the spring cloud contract plugin. You will also generate stubs and push them out. On the consumer side you can use the docker spring cloud  stub runner image to run the stubs.

Comment: That resolves part of my question - tests on consumer side.
What about tests on server side (node)?

Comment: So we describe in docs and in the article how to do server tests if server is in nodejs. I don't understand the question

Comment: It turned out I was missing `ifconfig` on my pc and that's why `./run_tests.sh` didn't work as expected according to article.
Thanks for your contribution :)